# How can I use concat in Greenplum

Tags: sql, airflow, greenplum

I have a function where I must concat 'text'||'#'||column_name
How can I concat in my query using following script?

```
p_sql_text := '
       select
            ''MDMP'' as bk_src_cd,
            ''MDMP'||'#'||'counterparty_id as bk_id
       from stg.t_zk3_'|| p_table_name
```

When I run my workflow in airflow I have the following error:

> ERROR loading table:unterminated quoted string at or near
> "'MDMP#counterparty_id as bk_id

From airflow log:

```
select 
        'MDMP' as bk_src_cd,
        'MDMP#counterparty_id as bk_id
           from stg.t_zk3_865445fgf5654f) tmp
```

Comment: Take a look at the p_sql_text contents, and you'll probably see,

Answer (score 0):

This method is working
''MDMP''||''#''||counterparty_id as bk_id

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).